# How to get access to variable in angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular1.6

I have a binding `eid: '@'`

In my constructor I have a method:

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    console.log('eid: ', this.eid)
}
console.log("eid in another place: ", this.eid)
```

When I execute this code (by entering certain page of my app) I see in console

```
eid in another place:  undefined
eid:  1
```

How can I pass the `eid` variable to see it outside of the `onInit` function?

Comment: you can simply use a global variable

Comment: I tried but I still get an output like above. 
I think that the problem is which time when the variable is initialized.

Comment: What kind of javascript dialect are you using?

Comment: I use ES6 javascript dialect.

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6 Pre-assigning bindings has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version, so we strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible. Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called after the bindings have been assigned. For more informatiion, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $compile Service breaking changes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-).

Comment: @Claies `'@'` is for attribute binding, `'&'` is for expression binding, `'<'` is one-way input binding, `'='` is two-way binding and should be avoided going forward. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: @georgeawg thank you for information, but how can I use variable initialized in `$onInit()` method outside of this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the $ctrl special variable in the log:

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    console.log('eid: ', this.eid)
}
console.log("eid in another place: ", $ctrl.eid);
```

I've founded this blog "[Dissecting @ < & = bindings in AngularJS](http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/)" very helpufull.

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6 Pre-assigning bindings has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version, so we strongly recommend migrating your applications to not rely on it as soon as possible. Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called after the bindings have been assigned. For more informatiion, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $compile Service breaking changes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-compile-).